# php SimpleXML attributes are missing

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following xml document here:
Edit: (see below for sample)

I am using php/SimpleXML to covert it to an object to read it:

```
$xmlContent = file_get_contents($path . '/test.xml');
$tablesRaw = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tablesRaw);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I print_r I see attributes for field but attributes for acceptable-value do not show. Here is an example of the raw xml (I need the value attribute):

```
<acceptable-value value="0">
    Unknown
</acceptable-value>
```

This is what I see when I print_r:

```
[acceptable-values] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [acceptable-value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 
                    Unknown

                                                        [1] => 
                    Invalid

                                                        [2] => 
                    Deleted

                                                        [3] => 
                    Valid/Good

                                                        [4] => 
                    Inactive

                                                    )

                                            )
```

Any clues why the attributes are not showing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Request for some of the xml:

```
<field name="Address1Type" type="String"/>
<field name="Address2Street1" type="String"/>
<field name="Address2Street2" type="String"/>
<field name="Address2Type" type="String"/>
<field name="Address3Street1" type="String"/> 
<field name="Status" type="Integer" access="R">
            <acceptable-values>
                <acceptable-value value="0">
                    Unknown
                </acceptable-value>
                <acceptable-value value="1">
                    Invalid
                </acceptable-value>
                <acceptable-value value="2">
                    Deleted
                </acceptable-value>
                <acceptable-value value="3">
                    Valid/Good
                </acceptable-value>
                <acceptable-value value="4">
                    Inactive
                </acceptable-value>
            </acceptable-values>
        </field>
```

Comment: Will you copy/paste some of the original xml code, so I don't have to download it?

Comment: yeah, trying to get some to show

Comment: What version of PHP?  It prints the attributes for me..

Comment: Version 5.2.13. It prints the attribute 'value' specifically on acceptable-value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer here is not to use `print_r()` with SimpleXML objects. Because they are wrappers around non-PHP data, functions like that which would normally show the "whole" object don't really reflect what you're looking at.

The way to access an attribute with SimpleXML is to use the attribute name as though it was an array key (`$node['attribute']`); this does **not** mean that there is an array somewhere with that key, it is a function-call in disguise.

If you want to get a feel for which nodes you're looking at while writing SimpleXML code, check out [this `simplexml_dump()` function](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) which I wrote (feedback welcome).

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong but it looks like it is not working for me, you can see my code/output here http://i46.tinypic.com/wnqti.jpg

Comment: @joshmmo Apologies, I tend to run PHP with Notices suppressed, as they often complain about things I am happy with. I will update the function not to raise that Notice when I next log onto to my dev box. The output however is as expected - it doesn't attempt to recurse through the whole structure, just tell you that the current node is called 'tables' and contains 57 children called 'table'. `simplexml_dump($tablesRaw->children())` shows something more useful, or indeed `simplexml_dump($tablesRaw->table[22]->fields->field[31]->{'acceptable-values'}->children())`

Comment: very nice I like it. It would be nice as well if it could expand the whole object so to speak so I can see it all at once.

Comment: @joshmmo I've been considering what the best way to represent the "full" document/sub-tree would be, but struggling to think of one that would be any more readable than `->asXML()`...

Comment: Your simplexml_tree function was very useful for debugging, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the SimpleXMLElement object. In this case:

```
$xmlContent = file_get_contents($path . '/test.xml');
$tablesRaw = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);
$elements = $tablesRaw->table[22]->fields->field[31]->{'acceptable-values'}->children();
```

Now, you can iterate over each `acceptable-value` object and use the `attributes()` method:

```
foreach($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->attributes()->value . " ";
    echo trim($element[0]) . "\n";
}
```

With your XML, that will print:

```
0 Unknown
1 Invalid
2 Deleted
3 Valid/Good
4 Inactive
```

It doesn't rely on the array index, because the call to `attributes()` gets the actual attributes of the element. And `->value` gets the attribute with the name "value".