# Attributes from xml element not in simplexml array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to read through an REA-XML file and using simplexml to convert the xml into an array

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

There is a section in the XML that looks like this:

```
<images>
    <img id="a" modTime="2009-01-01-12:30:00" url="http://image.jpg" format="jpg"/>
    <img id="m" modTime="2009-01-01-12:30:00" url="https://image.jpg" format="jpg"/>
</images>
```

When converted to an array , an additional array element "@attributes" is created with the modTime etc in it.

However, in the same XML , same level:

```
<landDetails>
        <area unit="square">80</area>
        <frontage unit="meter">20</frontage>
        <depth unit="meter" side="rear">40</depth>
        <crossOver value="left"/>
</landDetails>
```

The "unit" attribute is missing completely, 
The value for "value" in the crossOver, is in an "@attributes" array, but the three other items for "unit" are missing completely from the var_dump

Why do the unit values not show up in the @attribute array, or anywhere else in the landDetails section?

full example XML:

http://rea-new-help.realestate.com.au.s159598.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/rental_sample.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quck pointer:
[php SimpleXML attributes are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432739/php-simplexml-attributes-are-missing)

Basically, SimpleXML and `print_r`/`var_dump` don't play nicely: if you iterate through the object tree e.g. `$xml->area` you'll see the object faithfully rendered:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [unit] => square ) [0] => 80 )
```

This is particularly true for Elements where there are both Attributes and Content.